# django admin shows every foreign key with the same name

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am developing an application with Python Django, I think I am making a very primitvie mistake, but I have no idea how to solve it,

as you can see in the following picture

[image]

the admin django panel when I need to insert a product doesn't show name of the Categories it only shows the name of the class here you can see Category Object is shown and not for example CategoryX and CategoryY that were previously inserted in db

here is my code this is models.py

```
 class Category(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
      description = models.CharField(max_length=120)


 class Product(models.Model):
      OfferCat = models.ForeignKey(OfferCat)
      Category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
      price = models.IntegerField()
      isOffered = models.BooleanField()
      newPrice = models.IntegerField()
      name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
      description = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

and here is the code in admin.py

```
   class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       list_display = ['name','description']
       inlines = [CategoryImageInline]


   class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ['name','description','isOffered','price','newPrice']
        inlines = [ProductImageInline]


   admin.site.register(Category,CategoryAdmin)
   admin.site.register(Product,ProductAdmin)
```

I need the django admin shows the name of the categories not name of the class
Thanks in advance for any helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a `__unicode__` method in the Category model:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```